# Spring jms:listener-container concurrency not working with parametrized value

Tags: java, spring, jms

I have a application with spring 2.5.6 that uses spring jms:listener-container

```
<jms:listener-container concurrency="25" acknowledge="auto"
 connection-factory="jmsCachingConnectionFactory"  cache="none">
```

I works perfectly but now I need do externalize the concurrency value in a properties file. I already have others properties being loaded without error.

I tried the below code:

```
<jms:listener-container concurrency="${spring.jms.concurrency}" acknowledge="auto"
 connection-factory="jmsCachingConnectionFactory"  cache="none">
```

But it prints a sort of a parsing error:

```
[2018-06-25 17:36:05,292] ERROR  [MSC service thread 1-1] context.ContextLoader => initWebApplicationContext: (ContextLoader.java:215) - Context initialization failed: org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Invalid concurrency value [${spring.jms.concurrency}]: only single maximum integer (e.g. "5") and minimum-maximum combo (e.g. "3-5") supported.
    Offending resource: class path resource [app-context.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "${spring.jms.concurrency}"
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.FailFastProblemReporter.error(FailFastProblemReporter.java:68)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:85)
```

Also tried to create a String bean and load the parameter then inject into the listener like below, but it print the same error

```
<bean id="concurrency" class="java.lang.String" >
    <constructor-arg value="${spring.jms.concurrency}" />
</bean>
```

Is there a way to externalize/parametrize the concurrency value in the spring jms listener-container.

PS. Currently using spring 2.5.6 and cannot upgrade it right now.

Comment: Is your PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer bean configured ?

Comment: You would need to upgrade. Place holder support for namespaces has to be baked into the namespaces themselves.

Comment: @DevendraBahirat The PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer is configured correctly and it is working on other bean. Just the jmsListener theat prints the error